# Putting remote Linux server in local VPN

Tags: linux, vpn, fedora, pfsense

I have a VPS running Fedora 21, that I'd like to automatically log in to my local network via VPN.  My local router is running a pfSense firewall, so my options are IPsec, L2TP, OpenVPN, and PPTP. Currently I use OpenVPN to log in to my home network remotely.

What is the best option for having the server remotely log-into my local network? Note that key/credential management will be an important part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use OpenVPN. Either put the VPS on the same OpenVPN instance you're using for remote access, or create a new OpenVPN server instance for VPSes. I do the latter to connect a slew of cheap test VPSes around the world back into my home network. The client export config archive option makes it easy to configure the VPS side.

Comment: Connecting my VPSes to my home network is what I'd had in mind.  I'm just wondering if there's an industry standard way of setting up OpenVPN connections that connect automatically at boot.  I see there is e.g. NetworkManager-openvpn, but this seems to be a GUI thing.

Comment: It's just enabled the same way any service is. I'm not sure about Fedora, but on Debian if you enable the OpenVPN service, it'll launch on /etc/openvpn/*.conf automatically at boot time.